# Why C++ streams use state bits?

Tags: c++

I've heard that C++ is used when more performance is needed. C++ streams use concepts of bits for handling unexpected inputs, formatting, etc. I think this is not good for the performance because the program must do comparisons on every read and write. For example in MSVC, some part of `std::basic_ostream::operator<<(int)` is implemented as follows:

```cpp
if (_Bfl == ios_base::oct || _Bfl == ios_base::hex) {
    _Tmp = static_cast<long>(static_cast<unsigned int>(_Val));
} else {
    _Tmp = static_cast<long>(_Val);
}
```

My question is, is the compiler optimization reduces these calculations? If not, why did the C++ standard adopt the concepts of state bits? Is this cost trivial?

For formatting like `cout << std::hex << 1234`, we can use format class like this:

```
struct Format
{
    std::ostream* optr;
    Format&& operator<< (int i) && { ... }
    Format&& operator<< (double d) && { ... }
    ...
    template <typename T>
    Format&& operator<<(const T& other) && {
        (*optr) << other;
        return std::move(*this);
    }
};

Format&& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Format&& format)
{
    format.optr = &os;
    return std::move(format);
}

...

std::cout << Format() << 123 << ' ' << 456;
```

Comment: What could be less trivial than bits?

Comment: I think the cost can be reduced by using something like templates.

Comment: compared to the cost of doing string formatting doing a simple boolean check is probably tiny

Comment: IMHO, templates are much more complex than bits and, therefore, I would say much more performance expensive. Cheapest operations in C++ are those made on pointers, bits, byte....

Comment: @NutCracker templates have no runtime complexity, since all they do is generate code at compile-time. Of course, that also means that they're useless against a runtime issue such as parsing errors, which makes this question moot.

Comment: Formatted input/output is always going to require choices because formatting by definition gives the programmer control. You can bypass formatted input/output by using unformatted (binary) input/output if you need. Though the speed of a test would be hard to measure imo.

Comment: @Quentin yeah, i know but i meant on this particular example OP has posted

Comment: In my opinion, streams are badly designed. Formatting should be part of the parameter, not the stream. The "pay what you use" is definitely not true for streams. Performance can be much better with a properly designed library, like the upcoming fmtlib.

Comment: So the cost is trivial, and utility has the priority than the performance in this case. Thanks for the comments to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despites what you may think, even the [stdlib](/questions/tagged/stdlib) itself isn't designed/implemented with *absolute*  performance in mind (but is or comes close in many situations). This is particular true for the streaming library which weren't designed for *critical* performance in mind.